# numpy reshape cannot do (a,b,c) to (a,b,c,1)?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I reshape from the tensor from (a,b,c) to (a,b,c,1), but it turns out (a,1,b,c) using numpy. anybody knows why? or is there any way to get (a,b,c,1) from (a,b,c)?

Comment: Reshaping a numpy array from (a, b, c) to (a, b, c, 1) should work. It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrate the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
your_array = np.expand_dims(your_array, axis=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use np.newaxis like the example below:

```
tensor1 = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]])
print(tensor1.shape)
```

output: (2, 3, 2)

```
tensor2 = tensor1[..., np.newaxis]
print(tensor2.shape)
```

output: (2, 3, 2, 1)